# Building FTDI drivers for Ubuntu

Tags: c, linux, gcc, makefile, linux-kernel

I need to build the ftdi_sio module since I am currently working on USB stuff and need to add some debug features to understand. I dont need to cross compile. I dont need to build for arm. I just need to find the source and Makefile for the ftdi_iso module. It looks like https://sourceforge.net/projects/ftdi-usb-sio/ is where all the files are placed but when I extract it, I see no Makefile. Does anyone know how to compile the file(the flags and the include) ?

Comment: And what prevents you to compile in-tree driver instead?

Comment: @AndyShevchenko, What exactly do you mean by in tree driver?

Comment: That one that is already exists in the official Linux kernel tree.

Comment: @AndyShevchenko, I just want to know if I can build it separately

Comment: It's unclear what you want. The driver is already in the upstream. You may build it either with kernel, or separately.

Comment: @AndyShevchenko , Without installing the kernel and the entire linux build system, what are the gcc params I need to pass to build this? THink of it like a single c file which I just write. I want to produce the .ko. i cant find the makefile to do this

Comment: Too simple for one file: `obj-m += your_c_module.o`

Comment: And you can't build modules without kernel minimum infrastructure installed. Seems you are asking something else than mentioned in the question. Update your post and think twice before.